# How to set and unset a body zoom level in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am writing a react application in which I need to set the zoom level of a particular page to 90%. I know that I can do it using **document.body.style.zoom = '90%'** as given below:

```
useEffect(() => {
    document.body.style.zoom = "90%";
  }, []);
```

It's a basic componentDidMount function in react using useEffect. But the problem is how to set the zoom level back to the default as it was before loading the page using componentDidUnmount?

Answer (score 4):

Add [cleanup effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect) as callback returned from `useEffect`.

> The clean-up function runs before the component is removed from the UI to prevent memory leaks.

```
const Zoom = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const initialValue = document.body.style.zoom;

    // Change zoom level on mount
    document.body.style.zoom = "150%";

    return () => {
      // Restore default value
      document.body.style.zoom = initialValue;
    };
  }, []);
  return <></>;
};
```

Such callback acts like `componentWillUnmount`.

[image: Edit confident-williams-izk82]

Comment: Yeah, thats setting to 100%. I need to calculate the zoom level before loading the page and set the zoom level to that default value when the component is unmounted

Comment: The problem is document.body.style.zoom can be used to set the values, but the current values cannot be taken from them. Have you seen this code in action? By pressing F12 and checking it on the console window will make it clear what I said.

Comment: Let me check it

Comment: Seems that it works, check attached codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-williams-izk82?file=/index.js:107-411

Comment: The code explains right? You cannot print the initial zoom percentage. Try console.log(initialValue) on page load, not on component rerender in codesandbox. Or can you print the initial zoom level beside the toggle.